# Jupyter notebook --- (<hr> tags) being rendered different colors

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

This has been bugging me for a bit. Does anyone know why these line breaks inserted in a markdown cell, `---`, are rendered differently in my notebook? When inspecting the HTML of the Jupyter notebook all of the line breaks appear the same, as an `<hr>`, yet some are rendered bolder than others.  This occurs regularly and is pretty annoying from a formatting point of view.

Thanks.

**Markdown cell input:**

[image]

**Rendered markdown cell:**

[image]

Comment: Happens to me too and driving me crazy! Did you find an answer to that?

Answer (score 1):

Kindly try to apply HTML inline style formatting e.g

```
<hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:black;background-color:black">
```

I most apply HTML knowledge to most markdown related formatting and has been working for me.